# Magento - How to untick "Use Default Value" on a Super product attribute programmatically?

Tags: magento

Here's the super product attributes for a configurable product in Magento:
[image: Super product attribute]

I'd really like all the "Use Default Value" checkboxes to be unticked for all store views all the time, like the bottom one in the screenshot.

I've written some code to change the price for all of these options programmatically in a store view, but this doesn't do anything on the front end if "Use Default Value" is ticked in the backend. Having some code that unticks this box would save me going back over all the configurable products (and all the store views) to untick them manually, and would prevent mistakes in the future with new products.

I can't see where this is managed in the database though, and I can't find any code to manage this checkbox. Can you help?

Comment: Oh no! You're right. The mere presence of a super product attribute in the store view unticks the box. For some reason I'd got it stuck in my head that it needed a value /and/ a flag setting somewhere. Thank you! (You should totally pop that comment in as an answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When changing attribute values programmatically setting the store id and attribute value should work. The Use Default Vaule checkbox will be unticked for the specified store.

To set it back to use the default value `setData('attribute_code', null)` can be used.